# Mismatched array sizes in 2D array

Tags: arrays, vhdl

I want to create a constant 2D array with configuration values to switch the configuration over a generic value. Each configuration consists of seven 8-Bit values:

```
entity Foo is
   Generic (   CONFIG      : INTEGER := 0;
           );
end Foo

...

type Config_t is array(0 downto 1, 0 to 6) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);

constant Configs        : Config_t  := ((x"39", x"08", x"06", x"17", x"01", x"02", x"0F"),
                                        (x"39", x"08", x"06", x"17", x"01", x"02", x"0C"),
                                        (others => (others => '0'))
                                        );
```

But I get an error

`[Synth 8-421] mismatched array sizes in rhs and lhs of assignment`

So what is wrong with this declaration? I don´t get it.

Comment: @BrianStinar Then why comment? ALL perfectly legal VHDL.

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. The rules for constructing an aggregate are found in IEEE Std 1076-2008 9.3.3.3 Array aggregates. The error here shows up in the array type declaration (5.3.2.1) which has no elements (5.3.2.2 Index constraints and discrete ranges, 5.2 Scalar types, 5.2.1) `0 downto 1` is a *null range*. `(others => (others => '0'))` should be `others => (others => (others => '0'))` or eliminated. There are already two elements for the first dimension once it isn't a null range (`is array (0 to 1, 0 to 6) of`), an others choice can be present regardless (9.3.3.3).

Comment: It's almost invariably better to simulate a design before synthesis, there are generally better error messages in simulators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `downto` must be with descending index values, and the 2 values are given explicitly, so skip the `others` part, resulting in:

```
type Config_t is array(1 downto 0, 0 to 6) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);

constant Configs        : Config_t  := ((x"39", x"08", x"06", x"17", x"01", x"02", x"0F"),
                                        (x"39", x"08", x"06", x"17", x"01", x"02", x"0C")
                                        );
```